If katakana "ヘ" originated from part of the Kanji "部", why isn't it "⻏" instead?
[First post, please be gentle if this is a bad question]

As far as my knowledge, katakana is evolved from picking a part out of kanji.

However, I can't seem to understand how the kana "ヘ" originated from "部". Wouldn't "⻏" be the expected kana for "he"?




よくない質問かもしれないけど、知識の範囲では、カタカナはかなりの部分が漢字から派生したものだと知っています。

しかし、カタカナの「ヘ」が「部」から生まれたのはあまりわかりません。

むしろ「⻏」のほうが自然なのではないでしょうか。




It might help to look at the hiragana へ transformation.

That would have ended up identical to ア.

If it would have ended up identical to ア, are you suggesting that the kana へ was deliberately modified to avoid ambiguity?

I think what's lacking here is that katakana is commonly described as being taken from parts of kanji, without any further elaboration (that sometimes the kanji could be in their cursive forms). This is in contrast to hiragana, which is almost always described as (or at least known to be) taken from kanji in their cursive forms. I don't think that hiragana へ had different origins from katakana ヘ, but charts that compare the two may not present them consistently (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana#/media/File:FlowRoot3824.svg).

ア and ヘ were developed from the radicals of 阿 and 部 respectively.  Just because these radicals appear to look the same does not make them the same; in particular, the one always appears on the left and the other on the right.  In fact, these radicals are actually developed from very different kanji, 阜 and 邑 respectively.
Additionally, these katakana are derived from the grass-style (草書) of writing and their form is taken from the appearance of their respective radicals as they appear in the grass-style.  My kanji dictionary (角川漢和中辞典) nicely shows this development.  In the grass-style, these radicals are rendered somewhat differently and from this difference it is not too hard to see how ア and ヘ got their distinctive shapes.

Here you can see the 草書 for 部
Here you can see the 草書 for 阿

So, when you see various sources showing the origin of the various kana, it can be a bit misleading; a part of the story has been omitted.  It's not really that a particular portion of the kanji was lifted and then used for the kana, but that a portion of the kanji as written in the grass-form was lifted and used for the kana.  This becomes more apparent when, for example, you look at the development of メ from 女.

Yes, I have always thought that the kanji in kaisho form was used. Thank you for the answer (and correcting this commonly seen misconception)!
